# Liquid nested capture within itself

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Hi i have some capture code in which the capture block is called within itself.

What is the purpose of this

```
                  {%- capture popup_text -%}
                    {{- popup_text -}}
                    <div class="product__popup drawer drawer--left cv-h" id="popup-text--{{ block.id }}" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" data-drawer>
                      <button type="button" class="drawer__close-button" aria-controls="popup-text--{{ block.id }}" data-drawer-toggle>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.close_drawer' | t }}</span>
                        {%- render 'icon-close' -%}
                      </button>

                      <div class="product__popup__inner" data-scroll>
                        <div class="product__popup__content rte">
                          {%- if popup_page == blank -%}
                            {{ 'products.product.popup_missing' | t }}
                          {%- elsif popup_content == blank -%}
                            {{ 'products.product.popup_text_missing' | t }}
                          {%- else -%}
                            {{ popup_content }}
                          {%- endif -%}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  {%- endcapture -%}
```

Comment: That's a recursion. If popup_text has a previous value, it will prepend at the top of that popup_text.